# Remove all elements which is duplicated in another array in ES6 syntax

Tags: reactjs, filter

```
var arr1= ['test', 'test1', 'test2', 'test3'];

var arr2= ['test', 'test1'];
```

expected output ['test2','test3']
I am able to achieve this in the browser console using -

```
arr1.filter(x => !arr2.includes(x));
```

But the problem is that "includes" seems to be not supporting in ES6.

Is there an alternative?
Thanks!

Comment: Includes works in ES6. How are you compiling

Comment: Have you seen this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1584370/how-to-merge-two-arrays-in-javascript-and-de-duplicate-items

Comment: Yeah, but it always merges from both arrays. I need content only from arr1 but removing entries which is present in arr2.

Comment: It gives me this error TS2339: Property 'includes' does not exist on type 'string[]' when I try generating bundle in react. After searching for fix I read that ES6 does not support this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this as an alternative:

```
const res= arr1.filter(x => arr2.indexOf(x.toString()) === -1)
```

Comment: indexOf was expecting string but x was of the type {}

Answer (score 1):

You can try.

```
var arr3 = arr1.filter(x => arr2.indexOf(x)<0);
```